# How to show (or hide) a hidden file

Tags: files, gui, hidden-files

I wanted to add classpath to my JDK. While searching a way to do it I noticed everyone open `.profile` file using terminal. But when I want to open and edit it with a text editor I couldn't see that file in Home folder.

Can someone tell me why is this. And also if possible how can I access `.profile` in home folder the GUI way.

Comment: Press Ctl+H while you're in nautilus.

Comment: Open terminal and try `cat ~/.profile`. Check the output, that is your .profile.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

**GUI way to show a hidden file or folder**

Hidden files and folder have names that start with a **.** (dot character). To toggle show/hide hidden files or folders use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.

Answer (score 18):

in Linux and Unix systems, the files starting with `.` (a dot) are hidden files. To see them with the ls command, add `-a` or `-A` at your ls.

```
ls -a /path/to/dir
```

or

```
ls -A ~
```

From the manual `man ls`:

```
   -a, --all
          do not ignore entries starting with .

   -A, --almost-all
          do not list implied . and ..
```

Comment: Also note files ending with a `~` may also be hidden.

Answer (score 6):

The reason you can't "see" .profile" is because the ls command
does not display file and directory names starting with `.`  - this
is the original device for "hiding" files in Unix.

You can still edit .profile by typing `emacs .profile`  (or whatever
editor you wish to use.)

And, you can "see" all your files by typing `ls -al`  which
asks for the "long form" (more informative) output for all specified
directory or file arguments.