# Can we set Nemo or Nautilus, to show hidden files per directory?

Tags: nautilus, nemo, gnu

Can we set somehow Nemo or Nautilus, to show hidden files per directory like the sorting, for example?

Comment: That's not what has been asked, the question is can it be set per directory. (the answer is no.

Comment: **Reviewers**: This is not a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/232649/how-to-show-a-hidden-file as the fundamental question being asked is whether it is possible to do per-directory show/hide of hidden files, rather than showing/hiding hidden files and folders globally in Nautilus or Nemo.

Comment: @ThomasWard, I find the suppression of my comments, without even letting me know, extremely annoying for this community...

Comment: @Vassilis Comments which are no longer serving a useful purpose are routinely purged, this isn't suppression of comments this is "standard cleanup tasks".  Your comment was flagged as "no longer needed" by the community, that's all.  It's not targeted suppression or suppression of comments, it's standard cleanup tasks is all, and you aren't alone in the 'group' of people whose comments are erased during these cleanups.

Answer (score 3):

I don't completely understand your question, but if you want to display hidden files, type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd>.

By default, this toggles the display of hidden files in most file managers, including Nautilus and Nemo.

Comment: The user knows how to show/hide files, but wonders if this is something that can be remembered on a per folder basis.

Answer (score 2):

In Nautilus, the "show/hide files" is global, and even applies to the file dialogs. So there for sure, you can't set it on a per folder basis.

In Nemo there is an option in the preferences under "Behavior" to "Ignore per-folder view preferences". I am not sure if that setting also applies to showing/hiding hidden files, but you may verify that the setting is off and see whether that causes nemo to also remember the setting on a per-folder basis. As I do not have nemo installed, I cannot verify at this time.

Comment: Nemo is the same as recent nautilus, it's a global preference, period.

Comment: Nemo is not the same as recent nautilus. Period. It has been forked early in the Gnome 3 shell development. More recent changes, among others on how the hidden state is registered in nautilus, will not necessarily have been merged in nemo. That the setting in nemo is also global is possible, but that is not because it is the same as recent nautilus.